# Anyone know the name of a cabinet hinge that will "kick out" 3 inches (see image)?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hinges, terminology

What is the name of a hinge that will kick out when open? (See image below - click to enlarge.) I have an adjacent blind that won't let me open my kitchen cabinet.

[image: Adjacent Window]
[image: proposed hinge connection]

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a cabinet hinge sold for this specific purpose but it's a good idea.  I hope you find it.  If not:

You could try adapting a *double action hinge*:

[image]

They are meant for doors swinging both ways.

When one of those is spring loaded (and usually ornate) it's a *saloon hinge*.

You could also possibly adapt a *tandem hinge* which is meant for double doors layered one on the other.

[image: tandem cabinet hinge]

Alternate approaches, if you don't find a hinge that works here, would be to

- reverse the door.  It looks like it would clear the window if the hinge was on the left.
- Move the cabinet a little to the left, if that's possible.  You could install a "gap fill" strip that you can buy at any hardware store given it's a common wood finish.

Answer (score 0):

A [concealed hinge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concealed_hinge_jig#Concealed_hinges) offers this functionality, or at least similar to what you seem to have:

[image]

(but the ones in my closet only do one inch, not three...)